# Norm of a symmetric matrix equals spectral radius

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, symmetric-matrices, spectral-radius

How do I prove that the norm of a matrix equals the absolutely largest eigenvalue of the matrix? This is the precise question:

> Let $A$ be a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix. Consider $A$ as an operator in $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by $x \mapsto Ax$. Prove that $\|A\| = \max_j |\lambda_j|$, where $\lambda_j$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

I've read the relevant sections in my literature over and over but can't find any clue on how to begin. A solution is suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405235/normal-operator-matrix-norm) but the notion of diagonal operator is not in my literature so it doesn't tell me very much. So, any other hints on how to solve the question? Thanks.

Comment: It is missing here completely in the discussion (but also in the task) that it is about the 2-norm. For other induced matrix norms (lub-norms) the situation is different.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The norm of a matrix is defined as 
\begin{equation}
\|A\| = \sup_{\|u\| = 1} \|Au\|
\end{equation}
Taking the singular value decomposition of the matrix $A$, we have
\begin{equation}
A = VD W^T
\end{equation}
where $V$ and $W$ are orthonormal and $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Since $V$ and $W$ are orthonormal, we have $\|V\| = 1$ and $\|W\| = 1$. Then $\|Av\| = \|D v\|$ for any vector $v$. Then we can maximize the norm of $Av$ by maximizing the norm of $Dv$.

By the definition of singular value decomposition, $D$ will have the singular values of $A$ on its main diagonal and will have zeros everywhere else. Let $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ denote these diagonal entries so that

\begin{equation}
D = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
              \lambda_1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
              0 & \lambda_2 & \ldots & 0 \\
              \vdots &  & \ddots & \vdots \\
             0 & 0 & \ldots & \lambda_n
          \end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

Taking some $v = (v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n)^T$, the product $Dv$ takes the form
\begin{equation}
Dv = \left(\begin{array}{c}
                  \lambda_1v_1 \\
                    \vdots \\
                  \lambda_nv_n 
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
Maximizing the norm of this is the same as maximizing the norm squared. Then we are trying to maximize the sum
\begin{equation}
S = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i^2v_i^2
\end{equation}
under the constraint that $v$ is a unit vector (i.e., $\sum_i v_i^2 = 1$). The maximum is attained by finding the largest $\lambda_i^2$ and setting its corresponding $v_i$ to $1$ and then setting each other $v_j$ to $0$. Then the maximum of $S$ (which is the norm squared) is the square of the absolutely largest eigenvalue of $A$. Taking the square root, we get the absolutely largest eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: @TedShifrin is it not up to me who asked the question to determine what is overkill? I asked for more details, the answer is not overkill, it's precisely what I needed.

Comment: @yoknapatawpha I understand your argument completely, thank you. However, I'm not able to convince myself that your choice of $x \in R^n$ yields the greatest $||Dx|||$?

Comment: @ErikVesterlund: My apologies for stepping on your toes.

Comment: @ErikVesterlund If you consider $S$ just as a weighted sum (putting aside for now that these are eigenvalues of $A$ we're dealing with), then intuitively it makes sense that to maximize the weighted sum, we'd assign all of the weight to the largest element in the sum. Considering the case of a $2 \times 2$ matrix, we'd just have $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ so that $S = \lambda_1^2v_1^2 + \lambda_2^2v_2^2$. Here, if $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2$, we'd maximize $S$ by setting $v_1 = 1$ and $v_2 = 0$ (and vice-versa if $\lambda_2 > \lambda_1$). The case of higher dimensions is similar. Does this help?

Comment: The fact that $\|W\| = 1$ and does not imply that $\|Wv\| = \|v\|$ for any vector $v$. It follows from $W$ being unitary.

Answer (score 22):

But the key point is exactly that your matrix is diagonalizable more specially that  you can find an orthonormal basis of eigenvector $e_i$ for which you have $A e_i=\lambda_i e_i$.

Then your write for $x=\sum x_ie_i$ and you have $Ax=\sum x_i\lambda_i e_i$ so that $\|Ax\|^2=\sum\lambda_i^2x_i^2$ now by definition of the norm of matrix it gives you $$\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}\leq|\lambda_{i_0}|$$ therefore $\|A\|\leq|\lambda_{i_0}|$ where $\lambda_{i_0}$ is the greatest eigenvalue . Finally the identity $\|Ae_{i_0}\|=\|\lambda_{i_0}e_i\|$ gives you the inequality $\|A\|\geq|\lambda_{i_0}|$.

Comment: How do you get that $||Ax||^2 = \sum \lambda_i^2 x_i^2$? At least in my book the matrix norm is not defined, not previous to the exercise anyway so, what is it?

Comment: just because  $(e_i)$ is an orthonormal basis, the whole question relies on the euclidean structure : the norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the one defined by  $\|x\|^2:=<x,x>=\sum x_i^2$. The fact that $e_i$ is orthonormal reads $<e_i,e_j>=\delta_{ij}$ which means $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise. Now compute $\|x\|^2=<x,x>=\sum x_ix_j<e_i,e_j>=\sum x_i^2$

Comment: Is it correct to draw the conclusion, that when we can find an eigenbasis, then the largest singular value always equals the largest eigenvalue?

Comment: So $x_i$ is not the elements of $x$ but its decomposition in the orthonormal basis $(e_i)$?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment. But I'd like to fix a mistake in @yoknapatawpha's answer. The overall idea is correct.

Take the singular value decomposition of $A$ as $$A=VDW^T$$ and then we are looking for $$\max_{||u||=1}||Au||=\max_{||u||=1}||VDW^Tu||.$$

Here V and W are both orthogonal matrices.
Because V is orthogonal, we have
$$||VDW^Tu||=||DW^Tu||.$$
Now denote $$x=W^Tu,$$ because W is orthogonal, we have $$||x||=||W^Tu||=||u||=1$$ and also there is an one-to-one mapping between $x$ and $u$. Thus the problem is equivalent to
$$\max_{||x||=1} ||Dx||$$
and the rest of the answer follows @yoknapatawpha's.

However, generally it's not right to say $\|Av\| = \|D v\|$ is true for any $v$. For example when
$$V=\left[\begin{matrix}1& 0\\0 & 1\end{matrix}\right], D=\left[\begin{matrix}2& 0\\0 & 1\end{matrix}\right], W=\left[\begin{matrix}0& 1\\1 & 0\end{matrix}\right], v=\left[\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right]$$
in this case you can check that $||Av||=1$ but $||Dv||=2$.

Answer (score -3):

**Hints:**

1)

> $$ A x = \lambda x \implies ||Ax|| = ||\lambda x||.$$

2)

> $$ ||A x||\leq ||A||\, ||x|| $$

3) Check the definition of the norm and conclude.

Comment: Unfortunately this only allows one to show that $\|A\|\geq\lambda_{i_0}$ and you the need the argument below to conclude in the other way.

Comment: Where are you using the symmetry hypothesis?

Comment: @TedShifrin: As you see it is a hint just to give the OP a start. Thanks for the comment. I appreciate it.