# Upper bound for spectral radius of matrix multiplications

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, spectral-radius, relaxations

For [Chebyshev iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_iteration), I want to find an upper bound for the highest eigenvalue of a matrix. I have a library in C++ to find eigenvalues for symmetric matrices, but for Chebyshev I need to find the upper bound for the highest eigenvalue of $D^{-1}A$, in which $D$ is the diagonal of A and A is symmetric. $D^{-1}A$ is in general non-symmetric. I wanted to do just like [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1193802/566177), but I think it requires the multiplication to be symmetric too, doesn't it? Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Did you find out anything?