# Bound on leading eigenvalue of compound transition kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I am reading a paper ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.12603)) which discusses discrete-time Markov processes on a state space $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$.

If $\pi(x, y)$ and $\pi_T(x, y)$ are both transition kernels, then consider
$$
\hat \pi(x, y) = \int_{\Omega} \pi(x, z) \pi_T(z, y) dz.
$$

The paper asserts (p. 5) that

> ...if we assume existence of a spectral gap for both $\pi$ and $π_T$ and denote the leading eigenvalues of these kernels by $\hat \lambda < 1, \lambda < 1$, and $λ_T < 1$, respectively, we have $\hat \lambda ≤ \lambda \lambda_T$.

**Question:** Why is this? I have found posts like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193763/eigenvalues-of-product-matrix) that look like they might be relevant, but tey are for matrices, whereas I think I am dealing with general kernels.

Thanks.