# Is the spectral radius of a matrix a convex norm of it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, spectral-radius

I am wondering if the spectral radius of a matrix is may be some kind of a norm ($l_{\infty}$-norm?) of it and if that is convex. Any pointers to related ideas would be helpful too.

Comment: For the matrix $\left[\matrix{0 & 1\\0 & 0}\right]$ the spectral radius is zero, but the matrix is not. Too bad for a norm.

Answer (score 1):

The spectral radius is the biggest eigenvalue of a matrix.

There is a linked norm called the spectral norm, which is infact the square root of the biggest eigenvalue of the matrix $A^*A$. (So not linked to its own spectral radius, but to the spectral radius of $A^*A$)

Norms are always convex. Due to triangle inequality and to the homogeneity.

**Edit:**

Biggest eigenvalue is of course not completly correct. You have to consider the absolute values of the eigenvalues...

Comment: Thanks. Is there any literature you can point me to which talks of trying to minimize the spectral norm of a matrix among a set of possible perturbations by trying to minimize the spectral norm of each perturbation to be added in every step. Does this ring a bell? coordinate descent and rounding  with spectral norm?

Answer (score 1):

Spectral radius is not itself a norm, but it is a lower bound of any matrix norm. That is, $\rho(A)\leq \| A\|$ for any matrix norm $\| \cdot \|.$ (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Gelfand%27s_formula))

Also, for symmetric matrices $A \in \mathbb{S}^n$, $\rho(A)=\| A\|_2$. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/603375/986095))

For some more bounds on $\rho(A)$, see [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1965-19-089/S0025-5718-1965-0171792-1/S0025-5718-1965-0171792-1.pdf).