# 2-norm of a diagonal matrix and its relation to largest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My problem is originated from the boxed inequality below. In the lemma, after Schur decomposition $D$ contains eigenvalues of $A$ along its diagonal.

I knew that $\|A \|_{2} =\|D\|_{2}$ as shown [Norm of a symmetric matrix equals spectral radius](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603375/norm-of-a-matrix-equals-greatest-eigenvalue).

And, $\|A \|_{2} = \sigma_{max}$ which is the maximum singular value of $A$.

So, $\|D \|_{2} =\|A\|_{2}=\sigma_{max} < \sqrt{\lambda_{max}} < \lambda_{max}$

I am not sure my argument is correct or not because if $0<\lambda_{max}<1$, e.g. $\lambda_{max} = 0.8$, then $\sigma_{max} = \sqrt{\lambda_{max}}=\sqrt(0.8) \approx 0.8944 > \lambda_{max}$.

So, my question is:

I do not understand why $\|D\|_2$ can be replaced by largest eigenvalue of $A$ (or absolute of the largest element of $D$ itself because of the result of Schur decomposition.)

### Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: @uniquesolution yes it is. Here $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the Euclidean operator norm and $\sigma_{max}$ is the greatest singular value.

Comment: reread the question that you've linked: the norm of a *symmetric* matrix is equal to the magnitude of its largest eigenvalue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$D$ is a *diagonal* matrix whose entries are the eigenvalues of of $A$.  The norm of any diagonal matrix (or for that matter, any normal matrix) is the maximum of the absolute values of its eigenvalues.  So, $\|D\|_2 = |\lambda|$.

Note, however, that it is *not* necessarily true that $\|A\| = \|D\|$.  In general, we have $\| A\| \geq \|D\|$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now $D$ being symmetric is crucial in my puzzle.