# Spectral radius of block-skew-hermitian matrix equals norm of block

Tags: matrices, reference-request, block-matrices, spectral-radius, spectral-norm

$$\rho\left(\left[\begin{matrix}0 & A \\ -A^{\dagger} & 0\end{matrix}\right]\right)=\|A\|$$
where $\rho(\cdot)$ is the spectral radius, $\|\cdot\|$ is the induced 2-norm.

**Question**: I am looking for either a reference or a much shorter proof for this statement.

**Proof**
The eigenvalues obey
$$\left|\begin{matrix}-\lambda I & A \\ -A^{\dagger} & -\lambda I\end{matrix}\right|=0$$
The [nonzero eigenvalues (of which the largest eigenvalue is one) obey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) 
$$\left|\begin{matrix}-\lambda I & A \\ -A^{\dagger} & -\lambda I\end{matrix}\right|=\left|\begin{matrix}-\lambda I\end{matrix}\right|\left|\begin{matrix}-\lambda I-A^{\dagger} A/\lambda\end{matrix}\right|=0$$
$$\left|\begin{matrix}-\lambda^2 I-A^{\dagger} A\end{matrix}\right|=0$$
Thus $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $-A^{\dagger} A$
$$\rho\left(\left[\begin{matrix}0 & A \\ -A^{\dagger} & 0\end{matrix}\right]\right)=\sqrt{\rho\left(A^{\dagger} A\right)}$$
But $A^{\dagger} A$ is hermitian, thus its [spectral radius equals its induced 2-norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603375/norm-of-a-symmetric-matrix-equals-spectral-radius)
$$\rho\left(\left[\begin{matrix}0 & A \\ -A^{\dagger} & 0\end{matrix}\right]\right)=\sqrt{\|A^{\dagger} A\|}$$
And [$\|A^{\dagger} A\|=\|A\|^2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83332/equality-for-matrix-norm-product-of-matrix-its-transpose-and-square-of-the-n)
$$\rho\left(\left[\begin{matrix}0 & A \\ -A^{\dagger} & 0\end{matrix}\right]\right)=\sqrt{\|A\|^2}=\|A\|$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to prove it. Call your block matrix $K$. For any unit vector $v=\pmatrix{x\\ y}$, consider $\|Kv\|$ directly and show that it is bounded above by $\|A\|$. Then show that this upper bound is attainable for some $v$.