# Norm of $\|Ax\|$ from the eigenvalue decomposition of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that we have a real symmetric matrix $A = VDV^T$ with known eigenvalue decomposition ($V$ is an orthogonal matrix). How to [show that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/603393/140670) $\|Ax\|_2 = \|Dx\|_2$?

It is straightorward to show that $\|Ax\|_2 = \|VDV^Tx\|_2 = \|DV^Tx\|_2$. But how to dispose of $V^T$ from the norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the case that $\|DV^Tx\| = \|Dx\|$ for a vector $x$, an orthogonal $V$, and a diagonal $D$.

It is the case, however, that $\|DV^T\| = \|D\|$.  Note that $V^T$ is orthogonal.  We may therefore say that
$$
\|DV^T\| = \max_{\|x\| = 1} \|DV^Tx\| = 
\max_{\|x\| = 1} \|D(V^Tx)\| = 
\max_{\|y\| = 1} \|Dy\| = \|D\|
$$

Comment: I don't understand what use you have for an example, but sure. Take
$$
D = \pmatrix{1\\&2}, \quad V = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}, \quad x = \pmatrix{1\\0}
$$