# Simultaneously bounding stable and unstable components

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am reading a passage from Perko's book about the Stable Manifold Theorem.  Here is the problem:

Let $\dot x = f(x)$ be a system where $f: E \subset \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ (with $E$ open and containing the origin).  The linearization of this system at $0$ is $\dot x = Ax$ where $A = Df(0)$.  Suppose $A$ has $k$ eigenvalues $\lambda_{j}$ with negative real part and $n - k$ eigenvalues $\lambda_{j}$ with positive real part.  Then we can write the eigendecomposition as $A = C\Lambda C^{-1}$ with

$\Lambda = \begin{bmatrix}
P & 0 \\
0 & Q
\end{bmatrix}$, where $P$ is the matrix for the first $k$ eigenvalues and $Q$ is the matrix for the remaining $n - k$ eigenvalues.  For the eigenvalues in $P$, choose $\alpha > 0$ sufficiently small so that $Re(\lambda_{j}) < -\alpha < 0$.

If we define $U(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
e^{Pt} & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ and $V(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & e^{Qt}
\end{bmatrix}$, then $\dot U = \Lambda U$ and $\dot V = \Lambda V$.

Now we get to something that Perko claims but does not prove:  There exists $K > 0$ sufficiently large and $\sigma > 0$ sufficiently small that

$\|U(t)\| \leq Ke^{-(\alpha + \sigma)t}$ for $t \geq 0$ and $\|V(t)\| \leq Ke^{\sigma t}$ for $t \leq 0$.

There is a discrete version of the first part discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561701/bound-on-the-norm-of-a-matrix-power), but that problem only addresses a matrix $A$ with no unstable subspace.  Can someone explain how to prove the full claim here?  Thanks.

Comment: Why is $A$ necessarily disgonalisable?

Comment: For sure, Perko does not assume diagonalizability.  A general Jordan form could be used for $\Lambda$, $P$, and $Q$.  I don't know how to prove the claim even for $A$ diagonalizable, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $\operatorname{re} \lambda < \beta$ for all $\lambda \in \sigma(B)$, then 
there is some $K$ such that $\|e^{Bt}\| \le K e^{\beta t}$ for all $t \ge 0$. (This
is true even if $B$ is not diagonalisable.)

Let $q = \min_{\lambda \in \sigma(Q)} \lambda$, $p = \max_{\lambda \in \sigma(P)} \lambda$.
Note that $p < -\alpha < 0 < q$.

Pick any $\sigma$ such that $p < -(\alpha+\sigma) < 0 < \sigma < q$.

Then there is a $K$ such that $\|e^{Pt} \| \le K e^{-(\alpha+\sigma)t}$ and $\|e^{-Qt}\| \le K e^{-\sigma t}$ for all $t \ge 0$.